# Is there a way using FFmpeg or software that would allow a user to upload a video with audio muted, but download the video with the audio rencoded?

Tags: wordpress, audio, video, ffmpeg, mute

Here is the background:

I am looking to start a video sharing site that would allow artists to upload their original dance choreography. The problem is that while the choreography is original, the music most likely won't be. I would like the user to be able to upload the video with the sound muted, but once it's downloaded the sound would return. I am looking to host this on a WordPress site but is there a way using FFmpeg or a plug-in that would accomplish this? I am a very novice programmer but I would like to to be able to suggest a solution to a plugin developer.

This would also allow me to display and play multiple videos on a page without having all of the audio overlap one another. Thanks in advance for your help!!!